Flutter App for SMS-Based Irrigation Control: Sending Commands & Receiving Status
I'm developing a Flutter mobile app to control an irrigation system remotely. The goal is to:
Send SMS commands like "ON" or "OFF" to turn the irrigation system on or off.
Receive SMS status updates from the irrigation system and display them in the app (e.g., "System Active" or "System Idle").
I've attempted using the url_launcher and flutter_sms packages, but they haven't provided the desired functionality.
